Filling a curved surface

I'm looking for a way to fill up this mask (or similar ones, the mask could be anywhere in the image, also on the border regions), without adjusting the location of the edges (so erode/dilute would be difficult here, also because the gap is rather big). I was looking at hough transform/convex hull to maybe fit something around, but these mainly seem to work with straight lines and regular shapes.
Would there be a good way to fit curved lines/other ways to fill this up?
We are using an older opencv version (still stuck on one of the 2.0 releases).
Any ideas or helpful tips?
EDIT: Added the source image as requested by some users.
Link to download the original tiff file so you have the full data:
https://wetransfer.com/downloads/9da1db113497ee034ee94ef974a3dedc20240823092022/45873e

Alpha shapes?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_shape     By 'fill' you mean you want to turn the irregular interior region white, while retaining the overall shape, but convex hull doesn't quite work because the overall shape is somewhat concave?  You could also probably do find contours and then somehow filter out segments that are below some threshold and join what remains, but may be hard to make that robust.

Invert the mask?

source data please.

@Dúthomhas what does that trivial operation gain?

How did he get that shape from the mask to begin with? Invert the mask, you get a perfect match for the fill.

what area do you think is to be filled here? perhaps you misunderstand that part. -- OP has no shape. OP has a binary image. OP wants a shape of specific attributes, which is not trivially obtainable from this image. -- this is not a C++ problem. this is a computer vision problem. inverting presents no step towards a solution. it is at most an implicit step as part of a solution.

I would agree with alpha shapes. I don't think OpenCV has code for that. an alpha shape algorithm could be devised to operate on a contour. other operations in OpenCV might solve this as well. I did ask for the source data because usually people cause their own problems with ill-advised filtering.

Hey Christoph, I added the source image. I've been looking into alpha shapes, but they tend to sink into the gap (aka, they seem to try to fit the hole into the shape). I also lose the curve in the original border.

My current best approach is by finding the contours, running over them and then for each point check which other contour points exist in a radius of x pixels. Then I run over these contour points and check how far into the contour they are. If I see a big discrepancy between the point distance and the distance in the contour I assume there is an issue and I connect the points + fill the gap that is closed by adding that line

opencv has a function for "convexity defects". you could target convexity defects of a certain "severity" and cut those out (straight connection), i.e. the bottom edge of this shape would be left alone.

what do we see in your picture? https://i.sstatic.net/kZle6P6b.jpg

it's a picture of an image projected on a curved screen. This specific case has two difficulties:

brightspot
non-uniform brightness causing the area to be outside of the region of interest to sometimes be lighter then certain regions inside the area of interest

The two cases separate are easy to fix, but this combination is making it rather a hard fix.

can you, in principle, obtain a picture of the surface with the projector blanked out? then you can just subtract and have the pure projector component. -- if you wanted to unwarp the projection, just having its outline isn't good enough. you should want to project a grid, or series of Gray code stripes (horizontal, vertical). then at least you can establish a mesh and deform that.

This is not complete answer, just an idea.
Blurring the binary mask and then binalizing smooths out the mask shape a bit.
So iterating this process may be able to narrow the gap gradually.
Of course, it will also affect areas other than gaps... but, this may be able to be used as a part of your whole process?
int main()
{
    cv::Mat SrcImg = cv::imread("SrcMask.png", cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
    if( SrcImg.empty() )return 0;
    cv::threshold( SrcImg, SrcImg, 128, 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY );
    cv::imshow( "SrcImg", SrcImg );

    //Test
    cv::Mat WorkBuff = SrcImg.clone();
    const int KernelSize = ( WorkBuff.rows/4 | 1 );  //* This is just tentative value. Need to find a good value.
    while( true )
    {
        //Blur then Binalize
        cv::GaussianBlur( WorkBuff, WorkBuff, cv::Size( KernelSize, KernelSize ), 0 );
        cv::threshold( WorkBuff, WorkBuff, 128, 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY );

        //This bitwise_or is to recover rounded(lost) white tip.
        cv::bitwise_or( SrcImg, WorkBuff, WorkBuff );

        cv::imshow( "Current", WorkBuff );
        if( cv::waitKey(250) == 'q' )break;
    }
    return 0;
}

